# На странице знаков за метки частично отсутствует перевод

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

На странице [знаков за метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) отсутствует перевод в одном месте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст:

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил перевод.

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16732

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.9.27.43649